# Reset button, to link to viewcontroller.h

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble, from calling a variable from view controller.h. I am new to coding.

```
-(IBAction)buttonReset:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self resetBoard];
}

-(void)resetBoard{
    s0.image = NULL;
    s1.image = NULL;
    s2.image = NULL;
    s3.image = NULL;
    s4.image = NULL;
    s5.image = NULL;
    s6.image = NULL;
    s7.image = NULL;
    s8.image = NULL;
```

viewcontroller.h code

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s0;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s7;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s8;
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean that the `buttonReset` method is not be called when you click the button?

Comment: You should access your property like this:`self.s0` or `_s0`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you synthesize all s0, s1, s2, etc in your implementation file. Use @synthesize otherwise you'll have to call these variables with an underscore prefixed like _s0, _s1, etc.